# How can I split the difference between two timestamps that contain more than one month in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a DataFrame similar to this one, which describes the travel start and end timestamps of kanban (containers) with components/parts that move around in a shop floor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_kanban': [244, 243, 8, 9, 29],
    'component': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'start': ['2021-01-23 11:51:39', '2021-01-28 08:11:48', '2021-01-30 06:32:32',
              '2021-02-01 11:21:39', '2021-02-02 17:03:18'],
    'end': ['2021-02-11 10:20:21', '2021-01-28 09:13:42', '2021-02-02 08:14:24',
            '2021-04-04 09:22:19', '2021-02-03 13:05:28']
})
```

Output:

```
    id_kanban   component   start                 end
0   244         A           2021-01-23 11:51:39   2021-02-11 10:20:21
1   243         A           2021-01-28 08:11:48   2021-01-28 09:13:42
2   8           B           2021-01-30 06:32:32   2021-02-02 08:14:24
3   9           B           2021-02-01 11:21:39   2021-04-04 09:22:19
4   29          C           2021-02-02 17:03:18   2021-02-03 13:05:28
```

So in this example, kanban 244 has travelled around the shop floor from the 23rd of January at 11:51:39 to the 11th of February at 10:20:21.

I'd like to compute the travel time for each kanban but split between months. So for kanban 244 I'd like to split the computation between January and February, i.e. compute the travel time from the 23rd of January to the 1st of February, and then from the 1st of February to the 11th of February.

My idea is to split the timestamps between months and to create a new row every time there is a change in month (including months that could be in between both timestamps, e.g. kanban 9 where the kanban has travelled throughout February, March and April).

Here is an example of the output I am thinking of:

```
    id_kanban   component   start                 end
0   244         A           2021-01-23 11:51:39   2021-02-01 00:00:00
1   244         A           2021-02-01 00:00:00   2021-02-11 10:20:21
2   243         A           2021-01-28 08:11:48   2021-01-28 09:13:42
3   8           B           2021-01-30 06:32:32   2021-02-01 00:00:00
4   8           B           2021-02-01 00:00:00   2021-02-02 08:14:24
5   9           B           2021-02-01 11:21:39   2021-03-01 00:00:00
6   9           B           2021-03-01 00:00:00   2021-04-01 00:00:00
7   9           B           2021-04-01 00:00:00   2021-04-04 09:22:19
8   29          C           2021-02-02 17:03:18   2021-02-03 13:05:28
```

I'd like to take advantage of vectorization with pandas as much as possible as opposed to a custom function to apply iteratively to every row as the dataset is large.

Any ideas on how to get from the first output to the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your new `DateTimeIndex` with `date_range` with a month frequency then return the interval:

```
def find_interval(sr):
    dti = pd.date_range(sr['start'], sr['end'], freq='M').normalize() \
              + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    return list(zip([sr['start']] + dti.tolist(), dti.tolist() + [sr['end']]))

df1 = df.apply(find_interval, axis=1).explode().apply(pd.Series)
df1 = df.drop(columns=['start', 'end']) \
        .join(df1).rename(columns={0: 'start', 1: 'end'})
```

Output

```
>>> df1
   id_kanban component               start                 end
0        244         A 2021-01-23 11:51:39 2021-02-01 00:00:00
0        244         A 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-02-11 10:20:21
1        243         A 2021-01-28 08:11:48 2021-01-28 09:13:42
2          8         B 2021-01-30 06:32:32 2021-02-01 00:00:00
2          8         B 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-02-02 08:14:24
3          9         B 2021-02-01 11:21:39 2021-03-01 00:00:00
3          9         B 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00
3          9         B 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-04-04 09:22:19
4         29         C 2021-02-02 17:03:18 2021-02-03 13:05:28
```

Comment: @LazyEval. I fixed my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: yeah this is great, thank you. I suppose there's no way to take advantage of pandas (numpy) vectorization for such a problem right? I.e. not use `.apply()`

Comment: No it's not possible due to kind of problem. Ty for your support.

Answer (score -1):

You could add columns to your Dataframe named January to December or (1 to 12) and calculate the time delta using start and end times.

first convert your datetime columns into datetime objects:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start)
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end)
```

Assuming you are calculating travel time for a specific year (2021).

```
year = 2021
for i in range(1,13):
    beg_date = pd.Timestamp(year = year, month = i, day = 1)
    if i != 12:
        end_date =  pd.Timestamp(year = year, month = i+1, day = 1)
    else:
        end_date =  pd.Timestamp(year = year+1, month = 1, day = 1)
    
    df[f'Travel_time(h)_{i}'] = 0 #start value
    
    #case 1: start and end are in the same month
    idx1 = df.end < end_date
    idx2 = df.start > beg_date
    delta = (df.end - df.start).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())/3600 #in hours
    df.loc[idx1 & idx2, f'Travel_time(h)_{i}'] = delta.loc[idx1 & idx2]
    
    #case 2: end date is outside but start is in the month
    idx1 = df.end > end_date
    idx2 = (df.start >= beg_date) & (df.start < end_date)
    delta = (end_date - df.start).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())/3600 #in hours
    df.loc[idx1 & idx2, f'Travel_time(h)_{i}'] = delta.loc[idx1 & idx2]
    
    #case 3: start date is outside but end date is inside the month
    idx1 = df.start < beg_date
    idx2 = (df.end >= beg_date) & (df.end < end_date)
    delta = (df.end - beg_date).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())/3600 #in hours
    df.loc[idx1 & idx2, f'Travel_time(h)_{i}'] = delta.loc[idx1 & idx2]
    
    #case 4: the month is fully in
    idx1 = df.start < beg_date
    idx2 = df.end > end_date
    delta = (end_date - beg_date).total_seconds()/3600
    df.loc[idx1 & idx2, f'Travel_time(h)_{i}'] = delta
```

Output:

```
df[df.columns[4:8]]
Out[160]: 
   Travel_time(h)_1  Travel_time(h)_2  Travel_time(h)_3  Travel_time(h)_4
0        204.139167        250.339167               0.0          0.000000
1          1.031667          0.000000               0.0          0.000000
2         41.457778         32.240000               0.0          0.000000
3          0.000000        660.639167             744.0         81.371944
4          0.000000         20.036111               0.0          0.000000
```