# Split row if certain date is within a date range using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-05', 10], ['A', '2022-09-05', '2022-09-15', 1], ['A', '2022-09-15', '2022-09-18', 12], ['B', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-03', 4], ['B', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-07', 7], ['B', '2022-09-07', '2022-09-12', 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['GROUP', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'value'])

  GROUP  start_date    end_date  value
0     A  2022-09-01  2022-09-05     10
1     A  2022-09-05  2022-09-15      1
2     A  2022-09-15  2022-09-18     12
3     B  2022-09-01  2022-09-03      4
4     B  2022-09-03  2022-09-07      7
5     B  2022-09-07  2022-09-12      9
```

I have a `certain_date`, for example, `2022-09-10`. I would like to split the row where the `certain_date` is in the range of `start_date` and `end_date` per row per group. If the `certain_date` is in the range of the two dates, the `end_date` of that row should change to `certain_date` and add an extra row below where the `start_date` is the `certain_date` and the `end_date` is the original `end_date` where the `value` should be the same for both rows. Here you can see the expected output:

```
certain_date = '2022-09-10'

data = [['A', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-05', 10], ['A', '2022-09-05', '2022-09-10', 1], ['A', '2022-09-10', '2022-09-15', 1], ['A', '2022-09-15', '2022-09-18', 12], ['B', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-03', 4], ['B', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-07', 7], ['B', '2022-09-07', '2022-09-10', 9], ['B', '2022-09-10', '2022-09-12', 9]]
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['GROUP', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'value'])

  GROUP  start_date    end_date  value
0     A  2022-09-01  2022-09-05     10
1     A  2022-09-05  2022-09-10      1
2     A  2022-09-10  2022-09-15      1
3     A  2022-09-15  2022-09-18     12
4     B  2022-09-01  2022-09-03      4
5     B  2022-09-03  2022-09-07      7
6     B  2022-09-07  2022-09-10      9
7     B  2022-09-10  2022-09-12      9
```

For `GROUP A` you can see that the `certain_date` is in the range of the dates in the second row of the dataframe. As you can see it gets to split the way I described above. So I was wondering if there is a way to solve this using `pandas`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676134/11472761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the matching rows, then concat the dataframe without those and the slice with changed start or stop:

```
certain_date = '2022-09-10'
# is date after start?
m1 = df['start_date'].lt(certain_date)
# is date before stop?
m2 = df['end_date'].gt(certain_date)
# is both? (you could do all in one line)
m = m1&m2

out = pd.concat([df[~m], # data without matches
                 # changed end
                 df[m].assign(end_date=certain_date),
                 # changed start
                 df[m].assign(start_date=certain_date)]).sort_index()
```

Alternative: one-liner conditional and shorter `concat`:

```
m = df['start_date'].lt(certain_date) & df['end_date'].gt(certain_date)

out = (pd  # changed start for matches
  .concat([df.assign(end_date=df['end_date'].mask(m, certain_date)),
           # extra rows for stop
           df[m].assign(start_date=certain_date)]).sort_index()
     )
```

output:

```
  GROUP  start_date    end_date  value
0     A  2022-09-01  2022-09-05     10
1     A  2022-09-05  2022-09-10      1
1     A  2022-09-10  2022-09-15      1
2     A  2022-09-15  2022-09-18     12
3     B  2022-09-01  2022-09-03      4
4     B  2022-09-03  2022-09-07      7
5     B  2022-09-07  2022-09-10      9
5     B  2022-09-10  2022-09-12      9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `start_date`, `certain_date` and `end_date` into list then explode the result

```py
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df.apply(lambda row: [[row['start_date'], certain_date],
                                                       [certain_date, row['end_date']]]
                                          if row['start_date'] < certain_date < row['end_date']
                                          else [row['start_date'], row['end_date']],
                                          axis=1, result_type='expand')
out = df.explode(['start_date', 'end_date'], ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(out)

  GROUP  start_date    end_date  value
0     A  2022-09-01  2022-09-05     10
1     A  2022-09-05  2022-09-10      1
2     A  2022-09-10  2022-09-15      1
3     A  2022-09-15  2022-09-18     12
4     B  2022-09-01  2022-09-03      4
5     B  2022-09-03  2022-09-07      7
6     B  2022-09-07  2022-09-10      9
7     B  2022-09-10  2022-09-12      9

print(df) before out step

  GROUP                start_date                  end_date  value
0     A                2022-09-01                2022-09-05     10
1     A  [2022-09-05, 2022-09-10]  [2022-09-10, 2022-09-15]      1
2     A                2022-09-15                2022-09-18     12
3     B                2022-09-01                2022-09-03      4
4     B                2022-09-03                2022-09-07      7
5     B  [2022-09-07, 2022-09-10]  [2022-09-10, 2022-09-12]      9
```