# How can I split the difference between two timestamps that contain more than one date in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am have a DataFrame that contains start and end dates for when a compressor is not running (downtime). Some entries start on one day and run through the next day. I am wanting to split these rows so that we can break down the data on a daily bases.

Below is a small example size of my data set. The 2nd entry has a start time and end time on different dates

Here is my Input code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Compressor #': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'start': ['2023-04-13 14:35:00', '2023-04-13 23:40:00', '2023-04-14 07:50:00',
              '2023-04-19 07:32:39'],
    'end': ['2023-04-13 16:05:00', '2023-04-14 02:00:00', '2023-04-14 10:45:00',
              '2023-04-19 08:41:08']
})
```

Here is the Input Dataframe I have:

```
       Compressor #                start                  end
0             0  2023-04-13 14:35:00  2023-04-13 16:05:00
1             0  2023-04-13 23:40:00  2023-04-14 02:00:00
2             0  2023-04-14 07:50:00  2023-04-14 10:45:00
3             0  2023-04-19 07:32:39  2023-04-19 08:41:08
```

I found a previous post that was similar but on a monthly bases ([How can I split the difference between two timestamps that contain more than one month in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088226/how-can-i-split-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-that-contain-more-than-one))

I tried to edit the solution here and this is what I came up with: (It is not working)

```
def find_interval(sr):
    dti = pd.date_range(sr['Start time'], sr['End time'], freq='D').normalize() \
              + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    return list(zip([sr['Start time']] + dti.tolist(), dti.tolist() + [sr['End time']]))

df2 = df.apply(find_interval, axis=1).explode().apply(pd.Series)
df2 = df.drop(columns=['Start time', 'End time']) \
        .join(df2).rename(columns={0: 'Start time', 1: 'End time'})
```

Here is the output I want:
[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZzYp.png)

Comment: we need you to provide the input as code to solve the problem, as in the post you linked. need text or code of input, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code from the posting you linked to fit your needs.

And I thought it was appropriate for the start and end columns to be of type datetime, so I converted the data type and then applied the code.

```
def find_interval(sr):
    dti = pd.date_range(str(sr['start']).split(' ')[0], str(sr['end']).split(' ')[0])    
    dti = dti[(dti > sr['start']) & (dti < sr['end'])].tolist()
    return list(zip([sr['start']] + dti, dti + [sr['end']]))


df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])  
out = df.apply(find_interval, axis=1).explode().apply(pd.Series, index=['start', 'end'])
out = df.drop(columns=['start', 'end']).join(out)
```

out

```
Compressor #    start   end
0   0   2023-04-13 14:35:00 2023-04-13 16:05:00
1   0   2023-04-13 23:40:00 2023-04-14 00:00:00
1   0   2023-04-14 00:00:00 2023-04-14 02:00:00
2   0   2023-04-14 07:50:00 2023-04-14 10:45:00
3   0   2023-04-19 07:32:39 2023-04-19 08:41:08
```

Comment: I could kiss you!